# Can the Cosmos itself be assumed as a reference frame?

Tags: special-relativity

Einstein believed that there are no reference frame in the universe in accord to his Special Relativity (SR). Now imagine a man, as the first observer, and his cat, as the second, are both at rest in a room occupied with several things like a desk, bags, some books, etc.  The man suddenly moves toward his cat; what does each of the cat and the man observe? From the standpoint of the cat only the man is approaching, whereas from man’s viewpoint not only his cat but also many objects in front of him like the wall, books and everything are located in back of the cat (also between the cat and him) are approaching.  Reciprocally, many other objects like the desk and everything behind the man are moving away from him.  This difference in observations is the cornerstone that revives the concept of absolute motion.
If we extend this phenomenon from a room to the whole cosmos we can easily realize that the observer who accelerates to a value of velocity always divides the set of universe, consisting of all objects (the cosmos), into two parts: 1)- objects, from a single electron to a great galaxy, that approach; and 2) objects that recede.  First of all, we showed that there are examples galore can show a difference in observation between two reference frames in terms of the existence of the other objects surrounded them, but can this phenomenon violate SR?

Comment: By the way, there is one super special frame, and that is the rest frame of the microwave background radiation from the big bang - a frame where the red-shift of the background radiation is the same in all directions.  I suspect this is the exact same frame where most of the matter in the universe is close to being at rest.  But Hypnosifl's comment is dead on - we do not believe any special dynamical equations pertain to this frame.

Answer (score 1):

If the cat is in an inertial frame and the man initially at rest relative to the cat and then moves relative to the cat, then the man *accelerates* and is no longer in an inertial frame. So only the calculations from the cat's standpoint would be the usual ones we ken and love from SR. There is more on this fundamental asymmetry between the reference frames in [Wikipedia's Discussion of the Twin Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox).

So this doesn't violate SR. If the man and the cat carry accelerometers, only the man's would show a nonzero reading at any time.

It is a common popular misconception that Einstein's big contribution was to say everything is relative. This is *not* true and never has been. Inertial frames are indeed special and acceleration, in the sense of that which one measures with an accelerometer, is absolute. You can have co-ordinate frames all locally comoving with an event (*i.e.* a point in spacetime, with the frames having that point as their origin) but moving relative to one another in all kinds of nonuniform accelerated motions, but in **at most only one** can one have an accelerometer that will read nought.

Comment: Which violation of the SR you see? Excluding accelerating frames, that are not the object of study of SR as Savanna says, in whatever inertial frame you move, with or without a cat, some objects will come to you, and some will recede. Of course, from the point of view of DIFFERENT frames, you will get that the objects that approach and those that recede may be DIFFERENT, and with DIFFERENT velocities.

Comment: NO, the difference between frames is not something Einstein tried to say. He believed indeed that in a complete vacuum universe with the existence of only two objects we cannot find which one is accelerated and of course he was true. But the mistake he made was that he extended this symmetrical-thought-experiment to our universe filled with so many other objects and he therefore claimed that there is no difference between two inertial systems even though one undergoes acceleration. And I am trying to say that his concept is correct in a vacuum universe not ours.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry Firtsly I think you seem to be talking about [Mach's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle), which is incompatible with general relativity. GR actually says that if there were only two objects in the universe, one can be inertial and the other accelerating and that experiment will always determine unambiguously which is the accelerating one. It's not something that changes just by switching between the reference frame of each object. Secondly, an inertial frame cannot undergo acceleration and still be an inertial frame. One of the main things that ...

Comment: ..Einstein Field equations tell us is what are the locally inertial frames. The EFE are like an "application note" that goes with Newton's first law: they *define* which frames Newton I will apply in. Any acceleration relative to these inertial frames must be begotten by a force other than gravitation.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance: I believe that a version of Mach's principle is capable of introducing a reference frame. But I do not actually mean by a reference frame as a specific place in space according to which we enable to arrange "real-physical-formulas"; but I want to find a way that very clearly distinguishes an inertial frame with a constant velocity from that with a previous acceleration to a constant velocity. I want to introduce a way through which both asymmetric and symmetric system of motions being resulted in correct outcomes by each observers. What if I tell you that

Comment: I have found a theory that I can write a comparison with Special relativity theory (SRT) as follows:

Comment: SRT: - There is no preferred frame.  
New Theory: - There is always a preferred frame if an asymmetric system of motions is being considered.
SRT: - The speed of light remains invariant from the viewpoints of the observers in all inertial reference frames, and light speed is the upper bound for material speed in the universe.
New Theory: - The speed of light remains invariant from the viewpoints of the observers in all inertial reference frames, and there is not an upper bound number for velocity in the universe.

Comment: SRT: - In two reference frames (A&B) with constant velocity relative to each other, the velocity of A   measured in B  and the velocity of B  measured in A , are of opposite sign but equal magnitude.
New Theory: - In two reference frames (A&B) with constant velocity relative to each other, the velocity of A  measured in B  and the velocity of B  measured in A , are not exactly equal in magnitude and are opposite in sign.

Comment: SRT: - From the viewpoints of the observers in two inertial reference frames, the clocks always run either with the same rate (relative velocity zero) or run slower (relative velocity not zero).

Comment: New Theory: - From the viewpoints of the observers in two inertial reference frames, clocks always run with the same rate (relative velocity is zero or a symmetric system of motions is considered).  However, the clocks should run slower (relative velocity is not zero) from the viewpoint of the observer in the permanent inertial reference frame and, vice versa, run faster from the viewpoint of the observer who experiences acceleration to a specific value of velocity and then continues in inertial reference frame with constant velocity (asymmetric system of motions is considered).

Comment: @Hypnosifl: See the above discussion from "@WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance" please.

Comment: @user65673 that's a grand theory, and intuitive to human thinking; but do the hypotheses and conjectures have any verifiable merit? I.e. are they based on or supported by experimental or observed evidence?